# How to mark parts of text to be persistent and replace the rest using regex?

Tags: python-3.x, regex, replace

I have a text like `s = '__[__Click here__](https://some_url_here.com/bla-bla)__'`.

I need to convert it to `__[Click here](https://some_url_here.com/bla-bla)__`

How to do it? (I don't understand how to mark some pieces of text to be untouchable).

For example when I do `re.sub(r'(__[)__(\w\W+)__(])', r'', s)` I receive `lick here(https://some_url_here.com/bla-bla)__`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
import re
s = '__[__Click here__](https://some_url_here.com/bla-bla)__'
print( re.sub(r'(__\[)__([^][]*?)__(]\([^()]*\)__)', r'\1\2\3', s) )
# => __[Click here](https://some_url_here.com/bla-bla)__
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/Je3QAv) and the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/1UNWRw/1).

**Details**

- `(__\[)` - Group 1 (`\1`): `__[` text
- `__` - a `__` string
- `([^][]*?)` - Group 2 (`\2`): any 0 or more chars other than `[` and `]`, as few as possible
- `__`   - a `__` string
- `(]\([^()]*\)__)`  - Group 3 (`\3`): `](`, then any 0 or more chars other than `(` and `)` and then `)__` string.

Comment: Thank you for the step-by-step explanation!